# Includes child and child's objects when the child object is not list or collection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Hi I am trying to include child and child's object by linq

here is my parent class

```
public class SharePost : BasePost
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}
```

here is my child class which is "Address"

```
public class Address
{
    public SharePost SharePost { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public Place Place { get; set; }
    public int PlaceId { get; set; }

    public Suburb Suburb { get; set; }
    public int SuburbId { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, `SharePost` and `Address` are one-to-one relationship. so they have the same primary key value. Then I want to include `Place` and `Suburb` object when I load SharePost Object. So I tried like this

```
public SharePost GetFullSharePost(int postId)
{
   return DataContext.SharePosts.Include(m => m.Address.Select((a => a.Suburb)) && (a => a.Place))
}
```

But the `Address.Select()` does not work. The Asp.net does not recognize the `Select()` method on Address. Does the `Select()` only work with List or `ICollection`? Then How can I include the `Place` and `Suburb` object in `Address` when I load `Sharepost` Object?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Select` when you want to include a collection. Try this instead:

```
return DataContext.SharePosts
    .Include(x => x.Address.Suburb)
    .Include(x => x.Address.Place);
```